# Integration tests for spring kafka producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I want to write tests for spring kafka producer and consumer. I have tried multiple ways:

1. EmbeddedKafka annotation
2. EmbeddedKafkaRule
3. EmbeddedKafkaBroker
   etc...

Every time I get one or the other error and all the examples posted on GitHub don't seem to run at all. I checked the spring kafka versions for compatibility as well.

Can someone share an example code base that was recently written and has seen it run successfully?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of tests in the [framework itself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/tree/master/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka).

This is probably the most extensive one...

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/1b9a9451feea7cca16903f1c990c74c6be9b8ffb/spring-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/EnableKafkaIntegrationTests.java#L164-L176